# Reference $\dot{x} = f(x)$ has a unique solution if $f$ is twice differentiable and its second derivative is uniformly continous

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the theorem that the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$ has a unique solution if $f$  is twice differentiable and its second derivative is uniformly continous

Comment: For that it is sufficient to have $f$ once continuously differentiable. What further properties of the solution does your theorem provide? You get thrice continuously differentiable from standard theorems. Use the standard example of $\dot x=x^2$ to see that you can not expect much more.

Comment: I only require existence of a unique solution, can you tell me where to find such a standard theorem? I would like to note that $f$ is a function from $E$ to $E$, with $E$ a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the theorem of Cauchy-Lipschitz, if $\partial f/\partial x$ exists and is continuous, the IVP has locally a unique solution. This is a consequence of the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf, as any continuously differentiable function is also locally Lipschitz. As the IVP leads to the integral equation
$$
x(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^tf(x(s))\,ds
$$
you see that the solution $x$ is one differentiability order higher than $f$. As $x$ is continuous, $f\circ x$ is continuous and thus the integral continuously differentiable. As $x$ and $f$ are $C^1$, so is the composition and thus the integral is $C^2$. As $x$ and $f$ are $C^2$,..., $x$ is also $C^3$.

---

Note that the classical example for dynamical blow-up, $\dot x=x^2$, satisfies your assumptions. Keep that in mind while making further conclusions.